# Как использовать пароль приложения Gmail в ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, gmail

Здравствуйте всем. Есть такой код для оправки сообщения с ящика Gmail

```
SqlCommand _command = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO BaseAccaunt(Login, Password, Email, Phone, Birthday, Status)
                                                VALUES(@Login, @Password, @Email, @Phone, @Birthday, @Status)", _connection);
            _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Login", TextBox1.Text);
            _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Password", TextBox2.Text);
            _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Email", TextBox4.Text);
            _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Phone", TextBox5.Text);
            _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Birthday", TextBox6.Text);
            _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Status", 0);
            _command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            string server = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["server"];
            string port = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["port"];
            string login = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["login"];
            string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];

            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            message.Subject = "Подтверждение регистрации";
            message.From = new MailAddress(login);
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(TextBox4.Text));
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5Provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] hashCode = md5Provider.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(TextBox1.Text + TextBox2.Text));
            string url = "http://localhost:6333/Check.aspx?code=" + BitConverter.ToString(hashCode).ToLower().Replace("-", "");
            message.Body = "перейдите по ссылке <A HREF="+url+">";
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Host = server;
            client.Port = Convert.ToInt32(port);
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(login, password);
            try
            {
                client.Send(message);
            }
            catch(Exception excep)
            {
                Label1.Text += " " + excep.Message;
                Label1.Visible = true;
            }
```

конфиг

```
<appSettings>
<add key="server" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
<add key="port" value="587"/>
<add key="login" value="test86spade@gmail.com"/>
<add key="password" value="5618131Sd"/>
```

Выдает исключительную ситуация при отправке -
Отклик сервера: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.

Как я понял из похожих тем надо
Сначала включить двухэтапную аутентификацию
После этого получите пароль для приложения и использовать его для отправки писем.

Двухэтапную я так понял надо делать через смс?(при испольовании пароля смс приходить не должно?)
И как использовать код приложения в моем коде?